# Javascript Does Not Work in Internet Explorer

Tags: 2010, javascript, internet-explorer

For my list I have created a custom `NewForm.aspx` and `EditForm.aspx` that uses a custom stylesheet and javascript/jQuery with spservices.

The page works wonderfully in Firefox.  But when I open the page in Internet Explorer I can see that the javascript does not run when the page is opened.

I tried loading the page whilst skipping the cache via <kbd>ctrl+F5</kbd> and it doesn't help.

If I open the Developer Tools to debug it, the page immediately begins to work!

In my master page I have set the document-mode to IE8.  And in Developer Tools I see that it is running for the default mode, which is IE8.

It almost seems like IE is not loading jQuery.  But I've no way to debug it; as soon as I enable Dev Tools in IE everything works.

What can I do to fix this?

Here are the dev tools settings:

[image: Dev Tools Settings]

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Well, yes, I *can*, but I'm not sure it is a code issue.  It works in IE if F12 Tools are enabled, but not when they aren't.  There are no javascript errors in the console.

Comment: and what isn't working correctly?

Comment: Hmmm. How do I make this more clear?  When the page loads in IE, the javascript will hide/show certain elements on the page, but I can see that the elements are not being affected by the javascript.  Only in IE.  And only if the Developer tools are not enabled.  So, in the CSS I mark some elements as hidden and use those css styles in the `NewForm.aspx` but certain ones are supposed to show on certain conditions, and they do not show like they ought to - but only in IE with dev mode off.

Comment: I really hate Internet Explorer.

Comment: Maybe we can continue in chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33417/ie-problems

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Delete all the console.log lines from your script. It errors out until the console is open, which is why it suddenly works when you open the console

Comment: Stupid Internet Explorer!

Comment: I would have gone years without figuring that out myself!

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7742862/2729937

Answer (score 0):

If You mean SharePoint  - try to use

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("yourfunction");
```

instead of

```
SP.SOD
```

Helped me in SharePoint Online.